# Got an error while executing "create-react-app my-app"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, node-modules

I'm new to NodeJS.
I have excuted the follwing commands.
1.npm install -g create-react-app
2.create-react-app my-app

while executing  the 2nd command i got an error like this

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

> uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall
>   E:\Projects\HighAvenue\Dashboard\dashboard\node_modules\uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
>   node lib/post_install.js
>
> npm ERR! file bash npm ERR! path bash npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm
>   ERR! errno ENOENT npm ERR! syscall spawn bash npm ERR!
>   uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall: `node lib/post_install.js`
>   npm ERR! spawn bash ENOENT npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the
>   uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall script. npm ERR! This is
>   probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging
>   output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\Soorya\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-06-26T05_00_45_645Z-debug.log
>
> Aborting installation.   npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel
>   error react react-dom react-scripts has failed.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanyou all for your reply.
I have fixed this issue after installing yarn.
Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Have you permission for create folder at that location where you try to install the package. if you are using use sudo command before your statements.

You can do this using the runas command with an administrator trust-level, or by right-clicking the program in the UI and choosing "run as administrator."

Thanks

Comment: this is the log details.

Comment: 28014 info linkStuff object-keys@1.0.12
28015 silly linkStuff object-keys@1.0.12 has E:\Projects\HighAvenue\Dashboard\dashboard\node_modules as its parent node_modules
28016 verbose linkBins object-keys@1.0.12
28017 verbose linkMans object-keys@1.0.12
28018 silly build define-properties@1.1.2
28019 info linkStuff define-properties@1.1.2
28020 silly linkStuff define-properties@1.1.2 has E:\Projects\HighAvenue\Dashboard\dashboard\node_modules as its parent node_modules
28021 verbose linkBins define-properties@1.1.2

Comment: please let me which OS on your system.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51036405/npm-start-not-working-in-reactjs-if-public-folder-is-inside-another-folder please answer my question in that link

Comment: i'm using windows 10

Comment: still getting same problem.  I have tried clearing npm cache, reinstalled nodejs, all environmental variables are perfectly set..but still not fixed..

Answer (score 0):

Your Node setup looks incorrect. It's not an issue with Create React App—it seems like you can't run any global Node commands.

It looks like ~/.node_modules_global/bin is not in your PATH environment variable so it can't execute global commands. That's just how Bash works—it can't guess where the command lies, you need to tell it. I would assume Node installation should do this by default but it depends on how you installed Node.

So make sure that directory is in your PATH and try again. If you use Bash, add this to your .profile and then restart the Terminal:

export PATH=$HOME/.node_modules_global/bin:$PATH

Comment: $ npm config set prefix /usr/local
$ sudo npm install -g create-react-app
$ create-react-app my-app

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51036405/npm-start-not-working-in-reactjs-if-public-folder-is-inside-another-folder please answer my question in that link