# "npm start" not working in reactjs if public folder is inside another folder

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have the following structure in my react project

```
  --project
      |
      --main
         |
         -- public
             |
              -- index.html
         -- src
             |
              -- index.js
         webpack.dev.config.js
         webpack.prod.config.js
      -- node_modules
      -- package.json
```

For the above structure, when I run **npm start**, I am getting below error

> Could not find a required file.   Name: index.html   Searched in:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\project\public

because the **public** folder is there inside **main** folder. How can I run the code? Please tell me.

**EDIT**

```
  output: {
    filename: 'js/[name].js',
    path: path.resolve('/main/public/'),
    publicPath: '/main/public'
  }
```

tried setting the path in webpack

Comment: You should change the public path in webpack.prod.config.js: https://github.com/coryhouse/react-slingshot/blob/master/webpack.config.prod.js#L23

Comment: Please check my question. I have updated it

Comment: Why only in webpack.prod? Why can't in webpack.dev? Of course I tried both and it's not working.

Comment: @Mr_Perfect did you solve your problem? I"m struggling with the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should change the public path in webpack.prod.config.js: https://github.com/coryhouse/react-slingshot/blob/master/webpack.config.prod.js#L23

Comment: Please tell me what should be the path based on my directory. Because I tried, and it's not working. I think I should setup in webpack.dev.config.js

Comment: Why only in webpack.prod? Why can't in webpack.dev? Of course I tried both and it's not working.